# Calling event in Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-events

How do you define event controller like in the route? I'm following this tutorial and the code in route is something like this where you can directly access an event.

**Route web.php**

```
Route::get('/sender', function(){
    return view('sender');
});
Route::post('/sender', function(){
    $message = request()->message;
    return event(new App\Events\PusherEvent($message));    
});
```

So I tried to use a controller instead. What I did was :

**Route web.php**

```
Route::get('/sender', 'TestingController@index');
Route::post('/sender', 'TestingController@index');
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestingController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $message){
        if($message){
            return event(new App\Events\PusherEvent($message));
        }
        return view('sender');
    }
}
```

But an error appear at controller because of `return event(new App\Events\PusherEvent($message));`

[image]

What is the right way to define the event? Thank you.

Comment: can you attach the error message?

Comment: $message = request()->message; to $message->message in controler maybe ??

Comment: @AlzafanChristian You are right! That is the cause. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, good luck..